# Pivot table - Get counts of values in field by key field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.4, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot table which displays counts of unique values per a key field:

[image]

I've tried a combo of `PivotTable` and `Statistics` but the results are not correct. The `PivotTable` doesn't produce what I expected. The pivot table produces rows with empty key field values, which shouldn't exist as all input rows have a key value. I'm confused as to what inputs are what for the tool. `Statistics` does work as expected.

```
#this code doesn't produce what I was hoping - adding field with key and new fields for each summary value
pivTab = arcpy.PivotTable_management (inputTable, keyFld, summaryFld, summaryFld, pivotTab) [0]
##note the tool produces empty strings for values where they should be null
##I fix this here before stats
sumStatsFc = arcpy.Statistics_analysis (pivotTab, sumStatsTab, "valX COUNT; valY COUNT; valZ COUNT", keyFld) [0]
```

I don't need the python code for the answer; just which tools to use and what their inputs are.

Note that using cursors, dictionaries, etc isn't ideal as data sets are large and memory issues arise.

Comment: Use pandas, pivot != one in Excel.

Comment: @FelixIP I have memory issues with pandas too.

Comment: Strange. I use it on 3.5 m records, for summary statistics after ArcGis froze at sorting stage. Took under 2 mins.

Comment: @FelixIP Hmmm I must not be using it properly. Feel free to provide an answer with Pandas if you'd like.

Comment: Did you actually try a cursor + dictionary?  I bet it'd be more memory efficient than loading everything into an array to use pandas

Answer (score 1):

Pandas does it with ease.

Script:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("mesh_2d",["ZONE_ID","D_CLASS"])
df=pd.DataFrame(tbl)
del tbl
df["V"]=[1]*len(df)
arcpy.AddMessage(df.head())
pTable=df.pivot_table(values='V', index=['ZONE_ID'], columns='D_CLASS', aggfunc='count')
arcpy.AddMessage('\n')
arcpy.AddMessage(pTable)
arcpy.AddMessage('\n')
pTable.to_csv ('c:/scratch/pivot.csv')
```

Message (note time when run from mxd!):
[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: I get a `MemoryError` while attempting `arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray`. The field is a text field, which 300k records.

Comment: It was my suspicion. Very long text. I'd replace it with acronym. In my example one if the fields is text as well and not very short.

Comment: Alternatively run frequency on 2 fields, and use pandas on output.