# How to put this in a for-loop? I'm recreating ArcMap's 'Tabulate Area' tool in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, fields-attributes, geopandas, for-loop

I have two shapefiles, a province with 39 municipalities and a land cover of the province.

Goal: get the sqm of each land cover classification for each municipality. For example, how much open forest, closed forest, eroded areas, etc. are there in Muni 1.

I managed to write a code that does this but only for one of the 39 municipalities.

```
gdf1 = gpd.read_file('munis.shp')
gdf2 = gpd.read_file('landcover.shp')

muni1 = gdf1.loc[gdf1['NAME_2'] == 'muni1'] # NAME_2 is field containing all munis
intersection = gpd.overlay(muni1, gdf2, how='intersection')
area = intersection['geometry'].map(lambda p: p.area)
print(area)
```

The result is the sqm of each land cover classification in `muni1`. How to insert this in a for-loop so I can do the process for each 39 municipalities? I tried this but not working:

```
for i in range(gdf1.shape[0]):
    munis = gdf1.loc[gdf1['NAME_2'][i]]
    intersection = gpd.overlay(munis, gdf2, how='intersection')
    area = intersection['geometry'].map(lambda p: p.area)
    print(area)

Result
KeyError: 'Abad' # first municipality if sorted alphabetically
```

Comment: Why not to use pivot table from pandas, e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353722/pivot-table-get-counts-of-values-in-field-by-key-field/353728#353728

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`loc` primarily "label of the index" based. So, for the first iteration `gdf1['NAME_2'][0]` returns `muni1`. Then you get error using `gdf1.loc['muni1']`, because Pandas interprets `'muni1'`(`'Abad'`) as index label, but it's value of `NAME_2`

You should change `munis = gdf1.loc[gdf1['NAME_2'][i]]`
into  `gdf1.loc[gdf1['NAME_2'] == gdf1['NAME_2'][i]]` in `for` loop.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I have so much to learn still in using for-loops. Thanks for the explanation too. Really heplful, @KadirSahbaz.