# Making a pivot table in ArcGIS using Standard license

Tags: arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, tools, pivot-table

Having issued with using the pivot table tool in ArcGIS Pro due to the license level, I want to know if any geographer here knows how to make the pivot table of pivot table-like output using a set of different geoprocessing tools.

- Pivot table tool is only accessible through Advanced level of license while mine is only Standard level.

Comment: Simply use Excel, or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353722/pivot-table-get-counts-of-values-in-field-by-key-field/353728#353728

Comment: As FelixIP suggested I often use Excel pivot tables with ArcGIS; never the ESRI tool.  If you don't have Excel you can use Libre Office's Calc to do the same and being open source it is free.  QGIS is free and you can use the Group Stats plugin for some pivot table functionality.  I typically use ArcGIS and QGIS together.